# What is the space between argv and argc on my stack?

Tags: c, debugging, x86, stack, x86-64

I have a very simply C program that I'm using with GDB to learn more about the stack:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  printf("argc is %d", argc);
  int i = 0;
  for(i; i<argc; i++){
    printf("argv at %d is %s", i, argv[i]);
  }
  return;
}
```

I compile this program using `gcc foo.c -g` and then run it gdb using `gdb ./a.out`. Inside gdb, I set a breakpoint at main using `b main`, and then show the stack pointer and base pointer:

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40053c: file foo.c, line 5.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf48) at foo.c:5
5     printf("argc is %d", argc);
(gdb) p $sp
$1 = (void *) 0x7fffffffde40

(gdb) p $rbp
$2 = (void *) 0x7fffffffde60

(gdb) x/8x $sp
0x7fffffffde40: 0xffffdf48  0x00007fff  0x00400440  0x00000001
0x7fffffffde50: 0xffffdf40  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000

(gdb) p &argv
$3 = (char ***) 0x7fffffffde40
(gdb) p &argc
$4 = (int *) 0x7fffffffde4c
```

So I can see here that argv is pointing to the same address as $sp, the top of the stack, `0x7fffffffde40`. And I also see that argc's address is shortly thereafter at `0x7fffffffde4c`.

However, I'm not sure what the data at `0x7fffffffde48` through `0x7fffffffde4b` is holding. Is it anything important, or just garbage? Why isn't argv directly adjacent to argc on the stack?

Thanks!

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408900/question-about-pointer-alignment

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37713560/257645 (explains what _start does which sets up the stack with argc/argv)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [x86-64 System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html), function args are passed in registers.      (For links to other ABI docs, and explanations of what an ABI is, see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)

They only have addresses at all because `gcc -O0` spills them to the stack. This makes debugging C/C++ easier/more consistent:  everything has an address, and the value stored there is always up-to-date after every C statement.  However, it makes terribly inefficient asm code.  `gcc -Og` isn't as strict about storing to memory all the time, so you sometimes get "value optimized out", but it's still "optimized for debugging".

The other goal of gcc `-O0` is to compile fast, *not* to make good code.  So don't be surprised that it makes non-optimal decisions about laying out locals on the stack.  e.g. it could have only reserved 16 bytes, and put `argv` at `[rbp-16]` (8 byte aligned), argc at `[rbp-8]` (4 byte aligned), and kept the 4B temporary at `[rbp-4]` like gcc5.3's actual choice.

**The only "reason" for the gap between their actual storage locations is the inner workings of gcc's algorithms for laying out locals, before any extra optimization passes.**

---

To see what really happens when you compile a function, look at asm output (`-S`) from `-O3 -march=native -fverbose-asm` or something.  (Do this with functions that take inputs and return a value, instead of compile-time constant inputs, so they don't optimize away.)

This is the start of `main()`, as compiled by [gcc 5.3 on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer (with `-O0 -fverbose-asm`)](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:%27-xc+-std%3Dgnu99+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm+-O0%27,source:%27%23include%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char*+argv%5B%5D)%7B%0A++printf(%22argc+is+%25d%22,+argc)%3B%0A++int+i+%3D+0%3B%0A++for(i%3B+i%3Cargc%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++printf(%22argv+at+%25d+is+%25s%22,+i,+argv%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A++%7D%0A++return%3B%0A%7D%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
main:
    push    rbp     #
    mov     rbp, rsp  #,
    sub     rsp, 32   #,
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi   # argc, argc
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rsi   # argv, argv
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]   # tmp92, argc     # see how dumb gcc -O0 is: it reloads from memory instead of using the value in edi
    ...
```

On function entry, `edi` holds argc, and `rsi` holds argv.  `main()`'s caller (the libc C runtime startup code) put them there.  `mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rsi` is the instruction that stores argv to the bottom of the space reserved (with `sub rsp, 32`).  `[rbp-32]` happens to be the same address as `[rsp]`, but since gcc went to the trouble of making a stack frame (`-fomit-frame-pointer` is only the default at `-O1` or higher), it addresses locals with offsets from `rbp`.

---

In the 32bit SysV ABI, those args would already be in memory on the stack on function entry, because that ABI unfortunately doesn't use any registers for arg-passing.  The extra instructions and latency imposed by those extra store-forwarding round trips required by the legacy ABI are one of the reasons 32bit is slower than 64bit, even apart from the spills/reloads caused by having fewer registers.  Some 32bit Windows ABIs use 2 regs for arg-passing, e.g. the `__vectorcall` ABI.  That's good, because a lot of Windows programs are still distributed as 32bit.  (64bit Linux systems usually don't have to run any 32bit code.)

---

BTW, the ABI standard documents how argc/argv/envp are placed on the stack for your newly-`execve(2)`ed process, and that most registers other than `%rsp` must be assumed to contain garbage.  i.e. the *process* startup environment for `_start`, which is significantly different from what the C runtime code sets up before calling `main()`.  e.g. on entry to `_start`, the top of the stack isn't a return address, so you can't `ret`.  (You have to make an `exit(2)` system call, which is what eventually happens after you return from `main()`.)

## See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for lots more links to docs / tutorials / beginner-questions

---

Comment: So in short, in x64, arguments always are passed by register ... `-O0` will spill them into the stack of the `callee`, and I assume there is some spilling convention when the number of aguments from the `caller` exceed the number of registers.  And the spilling within the `callee` isn't necessarily optimal, nor strictly defined.  Is that close?

Comment: @rrauenza: yes, 6 regs are used for passing integer/pointer args, and beyond that the caller pushes them on the stack like in the 32bit ABI.  It's totally up to the caller what to do with them.  (Also, this isn't called a spill, because the values *need* to be in memory.  As I understand it, the term "spill" only applies when you could have kept something live in a register to avoid a reload for a later use.  e.g. storing a result into an array isn't a spill either; that's a required store.)

Comment: @rrauenza A compiler will only store them all to memory at `-O0` to help debugging.  Reloading them from memory again instead of using the value that's already in a register is *only* done to support debugging (e.g. `set argc = 10` in gdb). i.e. gcc spills everything even when it doesn't have to.  Compare the code with `-O1` or `-O3`, and notice how it keeps values live around a function call by putting them in a call-preserved register (which is saved/restored at the very start/end of the function), instead of spilling/reloading inside the loop. So yes, always non-optimal and not standardized

Answer (score 2):

It's about address alignment.  Processors prefer certain types to be aligned on certain boundaries.  Sometimes it is a hardware performance issue, sometimes it won't work at all, raising some kind of interrupt.  (Sometimes software traps are added to handle/hide these exceptions, but can hurt performance)

You'll see something similar in structs.  A struct won't be packed tightly unless you manually pack it.

```
int main() {
    struct {
       char c;
       void *p;
       int i;
    } a;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(void *));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
}
```

You'll see that `1+8+4` doesn't equal `24`.  That's because the `int` and `void *` are aligned:

```
$ ./a.out 
1
8
4
24
```

x86 and x86_64 are listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86

Here's also a nice table from Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/coding-for-performance-data-alignment-and-structures

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| DATATYPE | 32-BIT  | 64-BIT |
+----------+---------+--------+
|          |         |        |
| char     | 1       | 1      |
|          |         |        |
| short    | 2       | 2      |
|          |         |        |
| int      | 4       | 4      |
|          |         |        |
| long     | 8       | 8      |
|          |         |        |
| float    | 4       | 4      |
|          |         |        |
| double   | 8       | 8      |
|          |         |        |
| long     | long    | 8      |
|          |         |        |
| long     | double  | 4      |
|          |         |        |
| Any      | pointer | 4      |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question.  It looks like gcc could put `argv` at `[rbp-16]`, contiguous with `argc` at `[rbp-20]`, but it doesn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you think that is unique to main()'s setup?

Comment: No.  See my edit to my answer, where I tried to address this part better.  It's just an artifact of gcc's algorithms.

Comment: FWIW, that table may be valid for some ABIs, but not for, say, Windows. In Windows, a long is 4 bytes and aligned thus. I don't quite understand the last few entries (long long, long double, Any pointer?). They look wrong for any ABI.